# Package 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.10' was restored using '

Tags: c#, xamarin

> Package 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.10' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

I have this warning in the NuGet package of Microsoft.Net.Http and Microsoft.Bcl.Buil hough the project compiles but I am not sure if I need to worry about it as the last line says:

> This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

Below is the exact warning

> Package 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.10' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

[NU1701](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hsra1.png)

This appears when I want to archive to publish the app, in debug mode it works without any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **[Microsoft.Bcl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl/)** document , Bcl need .Net Framwork 4.5 .

> This package is only required for projects targeting .NET Framework 4.5, Windows 8, Windows Phone Silverlight 8, or Windows Phone 8.1 when consuming a library that uses this package.

And from NU1701 warnning info :

> Package 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.10' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

You should change your projecr target framework from **.NETStandard** to **.NETFramework** .Having a look at this [discussion](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/141255/nuget-warning-nu1701-netframework-version-v4-6-1) about NU1701 .If project not using this nuget , also can remove it.